# How to give the controller access to the main app before the initialize() method in Java FX?

Tags: java, javafx, nullpointerexception

In my controller class I want to use an object inside the `intialize()` method. This object (and its getter) are defined in the Main class. For this reason, when I give the controller access to the Main application it is already too late, because the object is called without being initialized. This will result in a `NullPointerException`.

This is the method that calls the `.fxml` and its controller:

```
public void showConfigurationOverview() {
    try {
        // Load configuration overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/ConfigurationOverview.fxml"));
        AnchorPane configurationOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set configuration overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(configurationOverview);

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        ConfigurationOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If it is not possible to give this early access, How can i find a solution for this? Should I do something inside my controller class?

### EDIT:

Thanks for your answers. I have tried the solution of *mr mcwolf* and It is working good. However my `setMainApp` method in the Controller class was like this:

```
public void setMainApp(MainApp mainApp) {
    this.mainApp = mainApp;

    // Add observable list data to the table
    configurationTable.setItems(mainApp.getConfigurationData());
}
```

But I had to place the function to *add the observable list data to the table* somewhere else. Did I do the right thing?

In addition I want to try also to try the solution of *Slaw* (and *Fabian*), but I did not understand what are you actually doing and why should i pass `this` to the constructor of my Controller Class. Thanks in advance

Comment: Edit mine according your edit.

Comment: And to be more generic, if you use the @mrmcwolf solution, simply add `configurationTable.setItems(mainApp.getConfigurationData());` in the initialize method of your controller `ConfigurationOverviewController` .

Comment: Thanks I did the same. However in the solution of @mrmcwolf now i have a report from *Intellij* that states that `initialize()` method is never used now. Is that normal or it is just a mistake of the IDE? Because the application seems working fine.

Comment: Did you add @FXML annotation ?

Comment: yes, of course. you can check from this [img](https://imgur.com/a/8pZVXO6)

Comment: it seems to me that this message is slightly misleading. just intellij can not find a fxml file to declare that it uses this class as a controller.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought because everything is working in the proper way right now. edit: can i mark only one answer? All three were very useful

Comment: You don't _have_ to pass `this` to the constructor. You can continue use `setMainApp` if you want. I mentioned the constructor option because it allows you to set things to a `final` variable (if you so choose); or perform other _pre-FXML_ initialization during instantiation of the controller rather than after. As for the controller factory, what specifically are you not understanding?

Comment: Also I have this problem that in my FXML file since I have removed the `fx:controller` tag, there are some issues with some methods assigned to some buttons. `<Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleNewConfiguration" prefWidth="100.0" text="New..." wrapText="true" />
                                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleEditConfiguration" prefWidth="100.0" text="Edit..." />`
The 2 methods and red-marked and no controller specified for top level element label is reported from Intellij.

Comment: Intellij can only do so much when it comes to FXML files. If no `fx:controller` is defined it might be able to figure out you are going to set one later that has all the appropriate methods. So, it does the _natural thing_ (/sarcasm) and decides you messed up rather than realizing it just doesn't know enough. So long as the controller you give the `FXMLLoader` via `setController(Object)` has all the correct methods you will be fine.

Comment: Thanks everything clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By `initialize()` I'm assuming you mean the `initialize()` method in the controller and not the `init()` method in your `Application` class (let me know if I'm mistaken). There are two ways you can do this:

1. Don't use `fx:controller` in the FXML file. Rather, create your own instance and configure it. Then you call `loader.setController(controller)` *before* calling `load()`.
2. Use a controller factory via [`setControllerFactory(Callback)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader.html#setControllerFactory(javafx.util.Callback)). Here you would still use `fx:controller` and can actually pass `this` into the constructor of your controller class.

Example for option #2:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setLocation(/* your location */);
loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> {
    if (YourController.class.equals(clazz)) {
        return new YourController(this);
    } else {
        try {
            return clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex); // bail
        }
    }
});
Parent root = loader.load();
```

You might be able to remove the `if` check as well as everything inside `else` if you *know* that only `YourController` will be instantiated by the controller factory.

**Edit:** Alternative example for option #2

This was mentioned in the comments by fabian. I'm posting it here because it's much easier to read code in an answer than a comment.

```
loader.setControllerFactory(clazz -> {
    Object controller;
    try {
        controller = clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (ReflectiveOperationException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    if (controller instanceof BaseController) {
        ((BaseController) controller).setMainApp(this);
    }
    return controller;
});
```

Where `BaseController` could be some interface or abstract class. This allows you to avoid checking for each and every type that needs special handling.

And, again mentioned by fabian, you could take this even further by introducing a dependency injection framework like AfterburnerFX or CDI (Context and Dependency Injection).

Comment: An alternative to considering all classes that require special handling you could use a interface or common base class. This would allow you to use the same logic for multiple classes requiring access to the application class. `Object controller; try { controller = clazz.newInstance(); } (ReflectiveOperationException ex) { throw new RuntimeException(ex); } if (controller instanceof MyType) ((MyType) controller).setMain(this); return controller;` It could be taken even one step further by using a dependency injection framework...

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can create a manual instance of the controller in which to inject the objects you need. Then you just submit the instance of `FXMLLoader`.

To do this, however, you must remove the `fx:controller` statement from your `FXML` file

```
public void showConfigurationOverview() {
    try {
        ConfigurationOverviewController controller = new ConfigurationOverviewController();
        controller.setMainApp(this);

        // Load configuration overview.
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
        loader.setLocation(MainApp.class.getResource("view/ConfigurationOverview.fxml"));
        loader.setController(controller);
        AnchorPane configurationOverview = (AnchorPane) loader.load();

        // Set configuration overview into the center of root layout.
        rootLayout.setCenter(configurationOverview);

        // Give the controller access to the main app.
        //ConfigurationOverviewController controller = loader.getController();
        //controller.setMainApp(this);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One another solution could be the following one (even if the two previous ones also work). Remove the `fx:controller` from your FMXL file and load it as follow :

```
public void showConfigurationOverview() {
    // Give the controller access to the main app.
    ConfigurationOverviewController controller = new ConfigurationOverviewController(this);
    root.setCenter(controller.getConfigurationOverview());
}
```

And change your controller like the following :

```
public class ConfigurationOverviewController {

    private AnchorPane configurationOverview;

    private MainApp mainApp;

    @FXML
    private TableView configurationTable;

    public ConfigurationOverviewController(MainApp pMain) {
        mainApp = pMain;
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("YOUR_FXML"));
        loader.setController(this);
        try {
            configurationOverview = (AnchorPane)loader.load();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public AnchorPane getConfigurationOverview() {
        return configurationOverview;
    }

    @FXML
    private void initialize() {
        // Do your stuff with mainApp
        configurationTable.setItems(mainApp.getConfigurationData());
    }

}
```

**Edit**

It is actually the solution #1 from [@slaw 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50812368/4629012).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, but I found that my Controller nulls link to the MainApp. That's why I made link `static`. After this I have not got any `NullPointerException`.
May be it will be helpful.

```
public class LoginController {
@FXML
private Label passwordLabl;

@FXML
private TextField passwordTexF;

public static WordLernApp wordLernApp;

public LoginController() {

    LoginController.wordLernApp = null;

}

public void setWordLernApp(WordLernApp wordLernApp) {
    LoginController.wordLernApp = wordLernApp;
}
```